# method pointer argument sets local ivar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, ocmock

Here's the method I want to test:

```
-(bool) myMethod:(NSArray*) argArray {
    self.mArray = argArray;
    if (self.mArray == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error - array is nil");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I am not quite sure how to setup a test for this method.  I want to test that if `argArray` is nil then it returns `NO`.  I also want to test that if `argArray` is not nil then I return `YES`.

I'm not sure if I should have a mock `NSArray` object and see if it passes/fails, or if I should just use a real `NSArray` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you can use real object. You should use mocking when you need to, that is when you stub any method.